# Custom UItabBarItem ( background image for the selected item)

Tags: objective-c, ios

i would like to implement a UItabBar like this image with a différent selected images for each tabBarItem. is this possible with iOS ? thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set the images via

UITabBarItem initializer initWithTitle:image:tag;

and the color via:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

though you'll need to specify the exact color to meet your liking.

Comment: Are you sure that's not forbidden ? i am sorry, it's very important for me to say yes we can or we can'not.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible programmatically using the tabBarItem.image property to change the image when viewDidLoad gets called.